How do I convert from IConfigurationSection to generic list?
How do I convert from IConfigurationSection to generic list of strings? I wish to add a list of emails to code read from appsettings.json. The .Get<List>(); isn't working. I'm not picking up how to do this from the microsoft documentation on IConfigurationSection.
EmailService.cs
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public EmailService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

   public Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetDistributionWhitelist()
   {
     var emails = _configuration.GetSection("DistributionWhitelist:Emails").Get<List<string>>();
     return emails;
   }
}

appsettings.json
"DistributionWhitelist": {
  "Emails": [
    "email1@example.com",
    "email2@example.com",
    "email3@example.com",
    "email4@example.com",
    "email5@example.com",
    "email6@example.com"
  ]
}


Are you certain this code builds? What exact error are you getting? Your method returns a Task<> but it looks like you are trying to return a List<>...

Strong suggestion.  do NOT inject IConfiguration into your class that needs config from appsettings.json. (This is very dotnetFramework thinkinkg)  Inject a POCO that wraps the values.  and IoC register those settings .. (right after you read them out of the appsettings file).  See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62431998/214977

No, this code does not compile. .Get<List>(); is not known.

public Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetDistributionWhitelist()
{
var emails = _configuration.GetSection("DistributionWhitelist:Emails").Get<IEnumerable<string>>();
return Task.FromResult(emails?? new List<string>());
}

replace the GetDistributionWhitelist() use this.
In my computer,it's success.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Consider using a class which allows validation using ValidateOnStart.
The following was coded with .NET Core 8.
Class
public class DistributionWhitelist
{
    public string[] Emails { get; set; }
}

In Program.cs

Validate section exist
Validate there are email addresses

builder.Services.AddOptions<DistributionWhitelist>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DistributionWhitelist)))
    .Validate<IConfiguration>(( _, configuration) => configuration.GetRequiredSection(nameof(DistributionWhitelist)) is not null)
    .Validate(dwl => dwl.Emails is not null, "Emails must have at least one entry")
    .ValidateOnStart();

In a page, code behind
public class EmailPageModel(IOptions<DistributionWhitelist> distributionWhitelist) : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string[]? DistributionWhitelists { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        DistributionWhitelists = distributionWhitelist.Value.Emails;
    }
}

Front end code
<ol>
    @foreach (var email in Model.DistributionWhitelists!)
    {
        <li>@email</li>
    }
</ol>

